# ORDER BY FIELD does not work with php

Tags: php, mysql

I need the MySQL parameter ORDER BY FIELD to order threads from a forum. 
Here the exact SQL command: `$ids` is `"19,3,12,256,1023"`

```
SELECT*
        FROM
            Threads
        WHERE
            ID IN ($ids)
        LIMIT
            $untere_schranke, 50
        ORDER BY FIELD(ID,$ids)
```

In phpMyAdmin it works fine but when I use php i get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 19,3,12,256,1023)' at line 15

Comment: set LIMIT **after** ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

Order by statement should be before the limit

```
order by FIELD(ID,$ids)
LIMIT
            $untere_schranke, 50
```

Comment: And as they say if you do not make mistake means you never tried :)